# How to automatically refer to names of spreaded columns - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

With the example straight from help:

```
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time)
stocksm %>% spread(stock, price)
```

Now I would like to create a adjusted copies of column `X`, `Y`, `Z` which are created using `spread`. I could just go for

```
stocksm %>% spread(stock, price) %>% mutate_at(vars(X, Y, Z), ~. + 1)
```

but it requires specifying names by hand, and as I would like to lock all of those operations in a function I need some way to pass the names of newly created columns. I also can't refer by columns id as the number of columns will have to be arbitrary. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Perhaps just change the orginal to:  ```stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time) %>% mutate(price=price+1)```

Comment: This doesn't generalise to my original case as the adjusting is far more complicated and has to be done after spread.

Comment: What is the use of thies two lines : `stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time)
stocksm %>% spread(stock, price)` .. ? What is the diffrence between stocks and the result ?

Comment: It's just to show that my columns of interest are the result of `spread` and only those should be mutated and I don't know their names explicitely.

Comment: What about ```stocksm %>% spread(stock, price) %>% mutate_at(unique(stocksm$stock), ~. + 1)```? If column names are the result of spread they are in the 'stock' column.

Comment: Yes, but if I would like to write a function that would spread indicated column I don't know its values before so I can't write the names of columns by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
stocksm %>% {
  variables <- unique(.$stock)
  spread(., stock, price) %>% mutate_at(vars(variables), ~. + 1)
}
```

But honestly, I cannot imagine a single example where it is beneficious to spread first.

Comment: Thanks. However, is there a way to write this using `dplyr` functions? I have tried `variables <- . %>% select(stock) %>% unique() ` but this doesn't work. I need this in order to use quasiquotation in my function, which I think doesn't work with reference by `$`.

Comment: Use `variables <- . %>% pull(stock) %>% unique()` instead. `select` will always return a `tibble`, but `unique` needs a vector.

Comment: Unfortunetely, this returns `Error: variables must evaluate to column positions or names, not a function`

Comment: Stop abusing the accept-function. This solution solved the problem in your question stated above. If you need other functionality, ask for it in another question, since this wouldn't get any more attention from others, because outdated and solved. Besides that, I can't reproduce your problem because you don't provide a minimal example that shows at least the character of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

stocksm %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(stock), paste0, ".spread") %>% 
  spread(stock, price) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with(".spread")), ~ . + 1) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(ends_with(".spread")), sub, 
            pattern = "\\.spread$", replacement = "")

#>          time           X            Y         Z
#> 1  2009-01-01  1.41134222  0.799908952 -2.547349
#> 2  2009-01-02 -0.03308714  1.510462889  2.909370
#> 3  2009-01-03  0.60722022 -1.725101030  4.697402
#> 4  2009-01-04  1.76681942 -2.538483592 -1.051576
#> 5  2009-01-05  0.05529327 -1.435663427  2.904005
#> 6  2009-01-06  2.69963414  2.364903583  3.957252
#> 7  2009-01-07  1.54475128 -4.289821346  3.043676
#> 8  2009-01-08  2.05165925  3.219704006 13.895450
#> 9  2009-01-09  0.05304517  0.008986952  5.257769
#> 10 2009-01-10  2.48281523  1.336480065  5.212230
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following ways:

Tell `mutate_at` to take all columns except `time`:

```
stocksm %>% 
  spread(stock, price) %>%
  mutate_at(setdiff(names(.),"time"), ~. + 1)
```

"Hack" `mutate_all` by grouping first, as it ignores grouping variable and your action is group independent :

```
stocksm %>% 
  spread(stock, price) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate_all(~. + 1) %>% 
  ungroup
```

**output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
         time      X      Y      Z
       <date>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2009-01-01  0.180  0.910  0.775
 2 2009-01-02  1.487  0.968  0.377
 3 2009-01-03  1.738  2.888 -4.883
 4 2009-01-04  1.576  2.642 -0.913
 5 2009-01-05  0.695  2.188  2.672
 6 2009-01-06  2.512  2.838  6.435
 7 2009-01-07  1.390  2.564  0.589
 8 2009-01-08  0.379  1.149  2.551
 9 2009-01-09 -1.215 -2.979  0.785
10 2009-01-10  2.125  2.240 -4.508
```